# How to send asynchronous state fetch to component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am currently working on a little app for fun. I ran into an issue with using axios and returning the response to my App component as updated state.

I then try to allow another component to use that piece of state, but I am not able to actually access the data. I can console.log(props) from within the List component, but I am not sure how to output the actual data as I am only able to output the promise results. I want to be able to output props.currentUser and have it be the googleId (using google Oauth2.0)..I am sure the solution is simple but, here is my code:

App.js ->

```
import React from 'react';
import helpers from '../helpers';
import List from './List';

class App extends React.Component{

  state = {
    currentUser: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      currentUser: helpers.fetchUser()
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <List currentUser={this.state.currentUser}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

helpers.js ->

```
import axios from 'axios';

var helpers = {
  fetchUser: async () => {
      const user = await axios.get('/api/current_user');

      return user.data;
  }
};

export default helpers;
```

List Component ->

```
import React from 'react';

const List = (props) => {

  const renderContent = () => {
      console.log(props);
      return <li>{props.currentUser}</li>
  }

  renderContent();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Grocery List</h1>
      <ul>

      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default List;
```

Output ->

```
{currentUser: null}
{currentUser: Promise}
    currentUser: Promise__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay all you need to change is :

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        currentUser: helpers.fetchUser()
    }));
}
```

to

```
componentDidMount() {
    helpers.fetchUser().then(data => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            currentUser: data
        }));
    })
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-axios-get-data)** (checkout the console)

> NOTE : `async` `await` always returns the `promise` it just make
>   synchronousonus behaviour inside the async function but end ot the
>   function it will always returns the promise.

Comment: @collin-desoto, will you please also accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Because `fetchUser` is an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), it returns a promise. Thus, in the `App` component, you have to call `setState` inside the `.then` of that promise, like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    helpers.fetchUser()
      .then(data => {
          this.setState(prevState => ({
              currentUser: data
          }));
      });
}
```